# google analytics embedded analytics api is not working without refresh the page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have implemented the google analytics embedded api in angularjs app it is working fine for the first time when refresh the page but after go to another route and coming back to the analytics page not showing the data.

the flowing image is the result after reloading the page.
[image]

when open the route without reload not showing the details this is screenshot of page in this time
[image]

this is my code at the header of the page

```
(function(w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
  g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {});
  g.analytics = {
    q: [],
    ready: function(f) {
      this.q.push(f);
    }
  };
  js = d.createElement(s);
  fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?96543238954346785456789';
  js.id = "googleCache";
  js.async = 1;
  // js.defer = true;
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs);
  js.onload = function() {
    g.load('analytics');
  };
}(window, document, 'script'));
```

this the code which I have in controller

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
  // Step 3: Authorize the user.
  var CLIENT_ID = "544116918374-r7mlqhknk2oj4mp5ia9ffss96e6ats6s.apps.googleusercontent.com";

  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
    container: 'auth-button'
  })
  // Step 4: Create the view selector.

  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });

  // // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

  var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
    reportType: 'ga',
    query: {
        'dimensions': 'ga:date',
        'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
        'start-date': '30daysAgo',
        'end-date': 'today',
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'LINE',
        container: 'timeline',
        options: {
        title: 'Visits per day',
        }
    }
  });


  // Step 6: Hook up the components to work together.
  gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
    viewSelector.execute();
  });


  viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
    // console.log(ids);
    var newIds = {
        query: {
        ids: ids
        }
    }
    timeline.set(newIds).execute();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google analytics embedded api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1) is based upon the Google APIs JavaScript client library.  JavaScript is a client sided langue.

Refresh tokens are not supported in this authorization method.

I have seen something in the past where something like node.js was used to request a new access token using the refresh token and this was then set to the front end JS code.   This is a little Hacky imo.

Comment: I know that JavaScript is a client side language but I want to get this details without reload in angularjs which is single page app and using ui-router for routing system

Comment: So you know JavaScript is a client side language and you know that the google analytics embededed api is JavaScript.   Then you should also know it is not designed to do what you are trying to do.    Angular applications are client-side applications that execute on the browser. This means you can not use a refresh token.  Which results in the fact that the user will need to authorize the application again when the access token has expired.